# Jquery UI: closing nested iframe modal dialogs

Tags: jquery, iframe, dialog, nested

I've got a UI structure that is misbehaving, and I'm wondering if adding some eyes to it will help me see something I'm missing, or, failing that, help me find a workaround.

I've got a page that loads a jquery UI modal dialog that contains an iframe.  That iframe loads a page that can open another modal containing another iframe.  That nested iframe contains a page with a button that should close the current modal.  However, that button does not work.  Here's a conceptual model of the layout (noting that each iframe is contained in a modal div):

```
 - page1
   - iframe1
     - page2
       - iframe2
         - page3
           - button -> close iframe2 (fails)
```

Note that this is conceptual, not how the DOM is actually laid out.  Also, there's actually a button in page2 that closes iframe1, and it works.  However, attempting the same function between page3 and iframe2 fails.  It is able to find the dialog div, but it gives me the "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'" jquery UI error.

Here are some additional notes that may help: each modal div, no matter the level of nesting, is appended to the main, top level body element due to the appendTo property of each dialog.  Adding buttons via the dialog function (such as the "X" buttons on display in the example) works.  So clearly there's a hidden hook that works fine.  Per other answers on SO, each iframe is already invoking the parent instance of jQuery to attempt to close their containing dialog.  Adding arbitrary numbers of .parent's to account for increased levels of nesting has not solved the issue.

Here is the full text of my sample app:
page1

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function make1() {
        var self = $("<div id='one'></div>");
        var frame = $("<iframe style='width:100%;height:100%' />");
        self.html(frame);
        self.dialog({
            title: 'One',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            appendTo: $(window.document).find('body'),
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            overlay: 0.5,
            close: function() {
                self.dialog('destroy');
            }
        });
        self.dialog('open');
        frame.attr("src", "http://localhost:81/page2.html");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="make1()">Open 1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

page2:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var dialog;

    function make2() {
        var self = $("<div id='two'></div>");
        dialog = self;
        var frame = $("<iframe style='width:100%;height:100%' />");
        self.html(frame);
        self.dialog({
            title: 'Two',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body'),
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            overlay: 0.5,
            close: function() {
                self.dialog('destroy');
            }
        });
        self.dialog('open');
        frame.attr("src", "http://localhost:81/page3.html");
    }

    function kill1() {
        window.parent.$("#one").dialog('close');
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="make2()">Open 2</button>
<button onclick="kill1()">Kill 1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

...and page3, the problem page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function kill2() {
        var dialog = window.parent.$("#two")
        if(dialog.length > 0) {
            alert("found it; closing dialog...");
            dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="kill2()">Kill 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The last, "Kill 2" button is what fails with an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a workaround.  Simply put, just delete all of the cruft that is created with the dialog.  **I must emphasize that this is very much a last resort, and even then it is not for everybody**.  It depends on several implementation details that are subject to be different between browsers and version of JQuery UI.  However, if you are in a scenario in which your clients' browsers are version locked, this should at least be worth investigating.

```
function kill2() {
    var dialog = window.parent.$("[aria-describedby='two']")
    if(dialog.length > 0) {     
        var zIndex = dialog.css("z-index") -1;
        var overlay;
        dialog.siblings(".ui-widget-overlay.ui-front").each(function(index, item) {
            if($(item).css("z-index") == zIndex)
                overlay = item;
        });
        if(overlay) {
            $(overlay).remove();
        }
        dialog.remove();
    }
}
```

Essentially, it locates the parent element of the dialog (again, by the implementation detail of it adding an aria-desribedby attribute to it), and then it searches siblings of that element for an overlay (if modal: true was supplied, this will be there.  Otherwise, it will not exist).  For arbitrary numbers of nested dialogs, you can find your appropriate overlay by looking for a z-index that is one less than that of your dialog.  Then, it removes the overlay and the dialog.

One key note is that this obviously bypasses any logic in the close: method supplied to the dialog.  You'll have to recreate that logic in this method if you want it to execute.